# Cannot set height with css units vw, vh or percentage

Tags: android, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am setting the width and height of a `div` as a proportion of the viewport width and height respectively in a Ionic app. This works pretty fine on the explorer on my computer and on a device with Android 4.4. However, this propperty seems to have no effect on Android 4.2 (the height is limited to the text height). If I replace `vh` by `%` it keeps working on v4.4 but still not on v4.2.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-content ng-controller="langController">

            ...

            <div id="language-selector" class="row">
                <h2>Idioma</h2>
            </div>

            ...

         </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#language-selector{
    height: 10vh !important;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #d1d3d4;
}
```

How can I make this work on Android v4.2?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Please vote or/and mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602691/android-css-font-size-vw-vh-responsive-alternative) to this issue and the only solution seems to write a JS function to update the height for Android <4.4.

See also at [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

One JavaScript solution could be:

```
// set initial height
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = (window.innerHeight / 10) + "px";
// change height on every resize event
window.onresize = function () {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = (window.innerHeight / 10) + "px";
}
```

Try it out and resize the window height:
http://jsfiddle.net/3eb68vf2/1/

Hope it helps!